# Multithreading deadlock in move command

Tags: c, multithreading, rwlock

I have the following problem when trying to implement a command similar to the move command in Linux, for another file system that has to be multithreaded.

When I'm trying to do : '''mv /a /b/a''' the program is locking the root directory for writing and a for writing. Then, since I can't release the locks cuz other thread might acquire them, I get into a deadlock situation when I try to lock the root for reading in the destination of the move command.

I'm trying to get my head around a possible solution for this. With the way my code is right now, when given a path /x/y/z , it locks every directory, for reading or for writing, depending on the command that I want to execute. So, using that, I'm able to identify if I can write /a into /b/a, because it checks if /a exists and if /b/a does not exist, but I still need to get around the deadlock situation.

Comment: How about: if the lock is already locked, don't lock it again? Or, use a recursive lock, where this is okay.

Comment: try to use `poll`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин what do you mean by poll? This is a file system that will work in a .txt file. It's not "real" per say. I could attribute a descriptor to each file, sure, but isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: @user253751 I'm doing that. The problem is, if the lock is locked for writing first, I then can't lock it for reading, and because I can't lock it, I can't just have my thread be stuck there, I guess, right?

Comment: there's `OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE` flag on windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile    . idk unix stuff on that.

Comment: dragonfly's hammer fs also done as file but i'm not sure you can use their stuff in any way